# What's the best way for me to bind data to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, data-binding

I'm quite new to C# (coming from a Java background) and I'm working on a `Form` to quickly manage different data (e.g. Users, Domains, Computers) along with providing utilities that use the data.

To avoid confusion the following is a summary of the example data structure;

```
<User>
    <Name>joe</Name>
    <Domain>europa</Domain>
</User>
<Domain>
    <Name>europa<Name>
<Domain>
<Domain>
    <Name>group</Name>
</Domain>
<Computer>
    <Name>localhost</Name>
</Computer>
```

In my `Form` I have tab pages for each data, each containing a `DataGridView` (containing a column for each member) to allow for simple management. I'm using a single `DataSet` which reads the data from an XML file (using a schema) when the `Form` Load event is fired. After reading the data I am setting the tables as the `DataSource` of their respective `DataGridView` using the code;

```
userDataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["User"];
domainDataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Domain"];
computerDataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Computer"];
```

This is working properly for the Domain and Computer `DataGridViews` as they only have single text columns which are mapped to the Name properties. However, the Domain column of for the User `DataGridView` is a combo box and I need that to contain all the possible Domains (e.g. europa, group) as well as the selected Domain being bound to User.Domain (also, the User.Domain being initially selected).

My main question is how I achieve the above but I also have some additional questions hopefully someone can answer;

1. I'm assuming that changes made to a `DataGridView` are immediately persisted in the underlying XML file as I am reading it from the build's output directory. Is this correct or is additional configuration/process required?
2. During my attempts at getting this to work I tried to use a `DataRelation` as follows;

   ```
   DataRelation dataRelation = new DataRelation("Domain users", 
       dataSet.Tables["Domain"].Columns["Domain"], 
       dataSet.Tables["User"].Columns["Domain"]);
   dataSet.Relations.Add(dataRelation);
   ```

   How exactly do `DataRelations` work and what effect do/can they have?

In case it helps you understand/explain I am using the SharpDevelop IDE for working on this application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already found out, the `DataGridView` is very powerful and does most of the work in an automagically way. Unfortunately you run into problems if these defaults doesn't match your preferences (like using a ComboBox for a text property).

To get the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` into the proper place you can do this programmatically within your code or (if possible) do it with the designer (in Visual Studio don't know if SharpDevelop supports it).

#### Using the (Visual Studio) Designer

For this scenario it is necessary that the structure of the data is known at design time by providing a class holding all (or more) informations as simple properties (like a person class with properties name, age, etc.). If this is available you can add a `BindingSource` to your control and click in the properties window at the button next to the *DataSource* property. Select *Add Project Data Source* and select *Object* and select your desired object.

Now you have a binding source configured with a specific type of DataSource. Next select your DataGridView and change the *DataSource* property to the recently created binding source.

After this the DataGridView will automatically be populated with a column for each property. Now you can easily step into the *Columns* property and change the behaviour and type of each column as you like.

To connect your concrete data with the DataGridView just apply your table to the binding source.

#### Doing the same at runtime

If you have Visual Studio and followed the above steps you can afterwards easily take a look into the Designer.cs file to find how Visual Studio did all the stuff. There is nothing you can't do also manually. So if you need to just do it.

Simply create a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, set the `DataPropertyName` and `HeaderText` and you've got a good starting point. Get the `IndexOf()` the column you want to replace, remove it and `Insert()` your freshly created column at the position you want.

Before the Grid can show some data (in the ComboBoxColumn) you need to provide a list with the possible values. For this purpose the comboBoxColumn has a *DataSource* property on itself where you can provide the desired values. With the simplest scenario you just provide an `ICollection<string>`, but you can also give something more complex like `List<KeyValuePair<Enum, string>>`. If that's the case you should also set the properties `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` to tell the ComboBox which properties of the objects should be used to populate the list.

Maybe with these informations given you should take a look at the [MSDN article about the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource.aspx) and study the example. This should give you some additional hints on how to set it up properly.

Comment: This all looks very useful. I'll try apply this logic to my application tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Also, SharpDevelop is the OpenSource equivalent of Visual Studio for poor folk like me :) and comes with almost all the same functionality.

Comment: @Alasdair: For the poor folks there also exists [Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/).

Comment: I've given this a try and I'm now not sure I understand the how the class (e.g. User, Domain) is being used. It could be SharpDevelop does not support it visually, but I can't even see how to bind a class to a 'BindingSource' at all. Are you able to provide code examples of all of the above?

Comment: @Oliver: I've tried that before but was unable to build an executable file and was limited to an .application build output. Is this not still the case? If not, I'll be glad to try it again. Especially if it helps solve this issue.

Comment: @Alasdair: As far as i know the limitations in 2008 Express was no Add-In support and no multi-language support (a solution could not hold a VB and a C# project). In 2010 Express still exists the single language limitation but the add-in support is now possible. Everything else is possible without any problems.

Comment: Switched to using Visual Studio Express Edition and must admit the 2010 version is a massive improvement on 2008. Switching IDE has made managing and applying data really simple using the UI. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Oliver: I've got everything setup now but I'm having problems with relations. I need a one-to-many relationship between the Domains and Users so that if a Domain is deleted/modified the Domain column in the User `DataGridView` is updated to reflect the change. I've tried multiple different attempts at creating this relationship in the XSD but nothing works as I keep getting different errors. Any suggestions or should I raise another question with more information?

Comment: @Alasdair: This is definitely a new question worth!